# How to use formik fieldarray index name within setFieldValue

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

If I have the following `<TimePicker/>` code which is part of a Formik FieldArray, how can I access the name `{`timeWindowGroups.${index}.timeWindowAdhocStartTime`}` within `setFieldValue()` ?

```
                <Field 
                  component={TimePicker} 
                  name={`myGroups.${index}.timeStartTime`}
                  label="Start Time" 
                  variant= "dialog"
                  inputVariant="outlined"
                  ampm={false}
                  openTo="hours"
                  views={["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]}
                  format="HH:mm:ss"
                  value={timeWindowAdhocStartTime}
                  onChange={(val)=> {
                    const hours = new Date(val).getHours();
                    const minutes = new Date(val).getMinutes();
                    const seconds = new Date(val).getSeconds();
                    formikProps.setFieldValue("{`myGroups.${index}.timeStartTime`}",`${hours}:${(minutes<10?'0':'')}${minutes}:${(seconds<10?'0':'')}${seconds}`)                                  
                    setStartTime(val)
                  }
                }                  
                />
```

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
formikProps.setFieldValue("{`myGroups.${index}.timeStartTime`}", new Date())
```

The main reason is that I need to ensure that I only return the time portion of the entered time provided by the user. At the moment, when the time is selected, it is prepends the date to the time, which I don't want.

Any ideas on how to access the FieldArray name as part of setFieldValue ?

Comment: HI, can anyone pls help with the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined when using the code supplied in the below answer. At the moment, I have the following import { TimePicker, DatePicker, DateTimePicker } from 'formik-material-ui-pickers'; Any ideas pls as to why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of field prop passed to the field component FormikTimePicker. It contains onChange, onBlur, name, and value of the field.

```
        const FormikTimePicker = ({ field, ...otherProps }) => {
            const handleChange = (val) => {
                const hours = new Date(val).getHours();
                const minutes = new Date(val).getMinutes();
                const seconds = new Date(val).getSeconds();
                field.onChange(`${hours}:${(minutes<10?'0':'')}${minutes}:${(seconds<10?'0':'')}${seconds}`)
            };
            return (
               <TimePicker
                   {...field}
                   onChange={handleChange}
                   // pass down other props needed
               />
            );
         };

          <Field 
              component={FormikTimePicker} 
              name={`myGroups.${index}.timeStartTime`}
              label="Start Time" 
              variant= "dialog"
              inputVariant="outlined"
              ampm={false}
              openTo="hours"
              views={["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]}
              format="HH:mm:ss"
            />
```

read more at https://formik.org/docs/api/field

Comment: Just so that I understand  correctly as I am new to react and formik and using my sample code snippet, how would I access fieldarray name as it could be at `index = 3` within the array within `setFieldValue`? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I am using: `import { TimePicker, DatePicker, DateTimePicker } from 'formik-material-ui-pickers';` and unsure how to get access to `field` and `form` ?

Comment: why do you need to use setFieldValue ? could you provide more context ?

Comment: I have updated my original question and added more context with regards to only wanting to return the time portion only from user selection. The `onChange` that I'm doing is trying to only return the time alone.

Comment: I  believe you are keeping time value in state, which defeats the purpose of using a formik. In my answer i just wrote a FormilTimePicker component which renders your TimePicker and overrides onChange to set startTime as h:m:s as string. I think that;s what you want

Comment: Hi, just tried your FormikTimePicker component and unfortunately as soon as I click into a time field, I receive the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined`. At the moment, I have the following `import { TimePicker, DatePicker, DateTimePicker } from 'formik-material-ui-pickers';` Any ideas pls as to why I might be getting this error?

Comment: can you share jsfiddle with working piece of code, so i can help you better